# getJSON no data returned

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to do a basic `getJSON()`, but I believe I am getting no results.

Here is my HTML/js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Management Sheet</title>
        <meta name="description" content="  ">
        <meta name="keywords" content="   ">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    $.getJSON("config.json",function(result){
                        $.each(result, function(i, field){
                            $("div").append(field + " ");
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section>
            <button>Actually Click me</button>
        </section>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my json

```
{
    'line1':'Mike B so cool',
    'line2':'Type your namasd',
    'line3':'763-345',
    'num_rows':'15',
    'num_cols':'3',
    'bgColorPage':'#f08008',
    'bgColorFilled':'#08f008',
    'bgColorEmpty':'#6f00ff'
}
```

when I click my button, I get no errors, but my div is not appended with anything.

Comment: Can you verify that 1) the ajax request is being made and 2) the response from the request is the specified JSON via something like [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?

Comment: I can tell that it is requesting the right page, but not too sure about the right type of request

Comment: You can click on the `config.json` link at the left panel, then in the right panel it will show the details, check both header and response tabs

Comment: Also add a `console.log(result)` as the first line in the callback method

Comment: your json is invalid check in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Your json string seems to be Ok. Check your ajax call config.json

Comment: apparently my json was not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
{
   "line1": "MikeBsocool",
   "line2": "Typeyournamasd",
   "line3": "763-345",
   "num_rows": "15",
   "num_cols": "3",
   "bgColorPage": "#f08008",
   "bgColorFilled": "#08f008",
   "bgColorEmpty": "#6f00ff"
}
```

use above `json` object and see.

Your code is perfect there is nothing wrong in your code use above object in json and test it you are guaranteed to be success.

Answer (score 0):

try with text();

```
$.getJSON("config.json",function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
        console.log();
        $("div").text(field + " ");
    });
});
```

Comment: still no luck and nothing in the console

Answer (score 0):

i tried your script and i don't why but if you change the single-quote for double-quote works:

```
 {
  "line1":"Mike B so cool",
  "line2":"Type your namasd",
  "line3":"763-345",
  "num_rows":"15",
  "num_cols":"3",
  "bgColorPage":"#f08008",
  "bgColorFilled":"#08f008",
  "bgColorEmpty":"#6f00ff"
 }
```